# jquery dropdownlist hide value if selected in second dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

Okay so I have two drop downs I want the selected item in dropdown one to be hidden in dropdown two and vice versa.

I have done the following so far can't seem to figure out the final step was hoping for a hand.

What I have currently is I have two lists that append to the dropdowns from and to, these list are looped over and append values to the dropdownlists, I then check for change event and when this occurs I remove values from a dropdown based on its index.

I am currently removing on selectedIndex, I want to remove on selectedValue rather then index but could not grasp that either.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var fromCurrencies = {

        FRO : 'Convert this currency',
        AUD : 'AUD, Australian Dollar',
        NZD : 'NZD, New Zealand Dollar',
        EUR : 'EUR, Euro',
        USD : 'USD, United States Dollar',
    };

    var toCurrencies = {
        TOC : 'To this currency',
        AUD : 'AUD, Australian Dollar',
        NZD : 'NZD, New Zealand Dollar',
        EUR : 'EUR, Euro',
        USD : 'USD, United States Dollar',
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var ddFrom = $(".ddConvertFrom");
        $.each(fromCurrencies, function (val, text) {
            ddFrom.append(
                $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
            );
        }); /*End ddFrom loop*/

        var ddTo = $(".ddConvertTo");
        $.each(toCurrencies, function (val, text) {
            ddTo.append(
                $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
            );
        }); /*End ddTo loop*/


    }); /*End document.ready function*/

    function doAction(){

        if ($('.ddConvertFrom').val == "" || $('.ddConvertFrom').get(0).selectedIndex == 0) {
            //Do nothing or hide...?
        } else {
            /*Hide selected value from other dropdown*/
            var index = $('.ddConvertFrom').get(0).selectedIndex;
            $('.ddConvertTo option:eq(' + index + ')').remove();
        }

    }

</script>
```

The html:

```
<div class="selectstyler">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddConvertFrom" OnChange="doAction()" CssClass="ddConvertFrom" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>

<div class="selectstyler">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddConvertTo" CssClass="ddConvertTo" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this and instead of using onChange attribute you can use change event handler.

```
$('select:first').change(function(){
            /*remove selected value from other dropdown*/
            var txt = $(this).val();
            $('.ddConvertTo option[value=' + txt + ']').remove();
 })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ue4Cm/1/

Comment: +1 for this, and for better, you should populate ddl everytime when change evet triggered.

Comment: This seems to work, except on the first change it doesn't remove the value on any change afterwards it changes.

Comment: @Anicho yes, because it should be within `$(document).ready...` check this http://jsfiddle.net/ue4Cm/2/

Comment: yay it works, last thing to select the second dropdown on `.change` I do `select:second` ?

Comment: there is no `:second` selector, use this `$('select:eq(1)')`

Comment: ah thanks, just realised I dont actually need logic lol because they will always be forced to select a new value. @undefined Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @undefined, yes, after the fix it worked and stopped removing from the second dropdown when it shouldn't have had. Well done.

Answer (score 3):

Purely for completeness to add to an already working answer from `undefined`.

To address the vice versa and the extended issue of re-adding those values including auto-selecting the previous value if it exists see: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/kZdNC/6/)

See below for the changes I made to your original scripts.

I'm sure the code below can be optimised on several levels but I only tried to get it working first. Making it pretty I leave to you :)

To start I re-factored your code so the values are attached in their respective methods.
The dropdowns are now fully cleared before the values are re-added.

First though we record the value of the currently selected option to ensure we can re-select it if it exists. Adds a more dynamic feel to it and saves the user form re-selecting manually.

See example of attaching values to the from-dropdown:

```
function attachFromValues() {
    var ddFrom = $(".ddConvertFrom");
    var selectedValue = ddFrom.val();
    var selectedIndex = 0;

    ddFrom.html("");
    var index = 0;
    $.each(fromCurrencies, function(val, text) {
        ddFrom.append(
        $('<option></option>').val(val).text(text));

        if (selectedValue == val) {
            selectedIndex = index;
        }

        index++;
    }); /*End ddFrom loop*/

    if (selectedIndex > 0) {
        ddFrom.get(0).selectedIndex = selectedIndex;
    }
};
```

I also re-factored the code which removes the value in the other dropdown calling the new re-factored methods to re-attach all values first before removing the specific value. That makes sure you do not end up with an empty dropdown after while.

See example of the `change` event of the to-dropdown:
*(taken from* `undefined`'s *answer, only added call to re-populate)*

```
$('select.ddConvertTo').change(function() {
    if ($('.ddConvertTo').val == "") {
        //Do nothing or hide...?
    } else { /*Hide selected value from other dropdown*/
        attachFromValues();
        var txt = $(this).val();
        $('.ddConvertFrom option[value=' + txt + ']').remove();
    }
})
```

For the complete code changes check the linked [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/kZdNC/6/)

**Edit (25-Jun-2012)**
Updated code as I noticed an inconsistency whereby the currencies did not re-set correctly if the default selection (index 0) was made. The latest version of this code now re-binds the currencies correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the vice versa tip that helped :D